# How to kick off js function with screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a left menu that I can slide out with a button click, but I want to hide it automatically when the screen width is below a certain size, so then the button click would bring it back.  What am I do wrong?

```
$(function () {

if (screen.width > 1200) {

    $(".ncLeftMenuButton").click(function () {
        $(".ncLeftMenuClosed").switchClass("ncLeftMenuClosed", "ncLeftMenu", 1000);
        $(".ncLeftMenu").switchClass("ncLeftMenu", "ncLeftMenuClosed", 1000);
        $(".ncMainBlockClosed").switchClass("ncMainBlockClosed", "ncMainBlock", 1000);
        $(".ncMainBlock").switchClass("ncMainBlock", "ncMainBlockClosed", 1000);
    });
}

else {
    $(".ncLeftMenuButton").load(function () {
        $(".ncLeftMenu").switchClass("ncLeftMenu", "ncLeftMenuClosed", 1000);
        $(".ncLeftMenuClosed").switchClass("ncLeftMenuClosed", "ncLeftMenu", 1000);
        $(".ncMainBlock").switchClass("ncMainBlock", "ncMainBlockClosed", 1000);
        $(".ncMainBlockClosed").switchClass("ncMainBlockClosed", "ncMainBlock", 1000);
    });
}

});
```

Comment: ITYM the _window_ width, not the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

screen.width will get the size of the user screen resolution. I guess you want to get the size of the browser window. Since you are using jQuery, you can use $(window).height() or even $(document).height();

```
if ($(window).height() > 1200) {
```

If you want to trigger the function when the browser is resized, It's a good idea to have a resize event:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).height() > 1200) {
     // Your code
  }
});
```

PS: You also can do what you want only by using css [@media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp).

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 1200px) {
    do some css things
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my own question.  thanks to anyone who helped.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $window = $(window);

// Function to handle changes to style classes based on window width
function checkWidth() {
    if ($window.width() < 1300) {
        $('.ncLeftMenu').removeClass('ncLeftMenu').addClass('ncLeftMenuClosed');
        $('.ncMainBlock').removeClass('ncMainBlock').addClass('ncMainBlockClosed');

                $(".ncLeftMenuButton").click(function () {
                    $(".ncLeftMenu").switchClass("ncLeftMenu", "ncLeftMenuClosed", 1000);
                    $(".ncLeftMenuClosed").switchClass("ncLeftMenuClosed", "ncLeftMenu", 1000);
                    $(".ncMainBlockClosed").switchClass("ncMainBlockClosed", "ncMainBlock", 1000);
                    $(".ncMainBlock").switchClass("ncMainBlock", "ncMainBlockClosed", 1000);

                });
    };

    if ($window.width() >= 1300) {
        $('.ncLeftMenuClosed').removeClass('ncLeftMenuClosed').addClass('ncLeftMenu');
        $('.ncMainBlockClosed').removeClass('ncMainBlockClosed').addClass('ncMainBlock');
    }
}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();

// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

});